# SetACL not propagating permissions correctly

Tags: windows, access-control-list

I don't know how many of you use SetACL do provide permissions for a user over some directories but I have found myself in a pretty weird predicament.

I am giving a certain user I have in my system, full permissions over two Windows directories in order to do certain actions (mainly deleting some files).

In one case I'm doing this to the Windows/Temp directory. What I'm seeing doing so, is that the user has -- as it should -- permissions over the whole directory and the containing files.

In the other case though, when doing the same to the Windows/Logs/CBS directory, I'm seeing that the user has permissions over certain files and not all of them.

What is more weird though is the fact that the whole thing does not make any sense given the creation/modification dates of the files. What I mean, is that there are files that were created on x-10 days ago on which the user correctly has permissions over them, there are files that were created on x-2 days ago following the same pattern, but there are files create on x-5 days ago on which the user does not have any permissions.

I cannot explain why this is happening but I'm trying to find a way to rectify this issue. My first idea is to switch over to 'icalcs' for doing the actual permission giving actions, as I think that a native Windows program should at least in theory perform better than the SetACL.

Has anyone encountered this? If yes what was the course of action in order to deal with this issue.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your question so that it is very targeted and very specific: For example: Explain the _precise_ behavior you are seeing, and tell _precisely_ what you tried and _precisely_ why it didn't work.